# Parse pricing and requests per second

Tags: parse-platform, request

Parse now allows us to send 30 requests/second, but it is not straightforward to me.

Quoting some info gathered:

- [Here](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-pricing-now-cheaper-and-simpler/) they say

> At 30 requests/sec, an app can send us 77.76 million API requests in
>   a month before needing to pay a dime.

So I suppose he meant

> send **up to** 77.76 million

- [Here](https://www.parse.com/questions/burst-limit), they suggest the rate of requests/second is calculated in a small window, **generally** a minute. This was answered about 2 years ago.
- On their [pricing faq page](https://parse.com/plans/faq/) they give an example:

> if an app is set to 30 requests/second, your app will hit its request
>   limit once it makes more than 1,800 requests over a 60 second period.

Suggesting that the window is one minute, even though they didn't clearly state it.

What intrigues me is that [they say](https://parse.com/plans):

> Pricing is pro-rated by the hour.

What does it mean? (sorry if it's obvious, English is not my first language)

Has anyone actually used parse and kept track of those request/second and burst/limits?

The only resource I found was [a guy saying](https://www.parse.com/questions/30-requests-per-second-equates-to-how-many-concurrent-users) he had a web application with 10,000 users/day staying in the website around 4min, and he had under 12r/s.

Moreover, if my app logs users' activities, would that be a good practice to cache this info then send it in random times like between from 3am-7am?

Any help is very appreciated. My company is deciding whether go forward with Parse or not, so it's very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They could have worded it better but it basically means the same as "We'll charge you for a minimum of 1 hour based on the request limit you have set".

Here's an example. Assume you are using a 40 rps settings ($100/month which is $100/720 hours). If you keep this for 1 minute, you'll be charged for 1 hour, roughly $1.40.

You can change the request limit as often as you want. So if your app/site receives peak traffic for only 12 hours/day, you can increase the limit just for those 12 hours and end up paying just for those 12 hours.

Check the third question (How frequently can I increase/decrease my request limit?) on the FAQ page at https://parse.com/plans/faq

> **How frequently can I increase/decrease my request limit?**
>   You can increase/decrease your request/limit as frequently as you would like
>   within a given month. We will prorate your charges on an hourly basis.

Comment: Thanks, your question was very useful. What I understood is that, since it charges per hour , if all my users are active only in a 6-hour-window per day, I could pay only for these 6 hours. However, there's no way to schedule it automatically, which means I'd have to set my limit twice a day, manually. Which is pretty unfeasible. Am I right?

Comment: @TeoInke That seems right. I looked through their documentation and I was surprised that Parse doesn't have an API to allow changes like these. Btw, if this answered your question, could you please mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear what the pro rating means as I understand the setting to be an explicit limit that you pay for. If your limit is exceeded then the requests fail. I don't think there's an option to allow for payment on demand when the limit is exceeded but pro rating would do that.

The one minute is accurate and that is the current limit management.

The point of the pricing model is that your service should be making money before you reach any of the limits. If you have enough users to hit the limits and you aren't making money then you need to reconsider your business plan. As such you shouldn't need to upload at random times of day as your users should naturally spread out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that can help you understand Parse's users request per second.

Parse estimates that the average app's active user will issue 10 requests. Thus, if you had a million users on a particular day, and their traffic was evenly spread throughout the day, you could estimate your app would need about 10,000,000 total API requests, or about 120 requests per second. Every app is different, therefore Parse encourages you to measure how many requests your users send.

You can read more this question answered directly from Parse staff here on [Parse/F&A link](https://www.parse.com/questions/30-requests-per-second-equates-to-how-many-concurrent-users)

Hope this helps